# Forge API Getting Empty Folders

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-designautomation

While Downloading **reportUrl** i am getting **status : failedDownload**

[image]

[image]

....REPORT LOG...
[image]

[image]

---

**Getting Empty Folder from Object of bucket**

> By another guy **FORGE APP** *clientID* and *cleientSecret* that ZIP and PDF is fine  but svf and dwg are blanks

```js
#!/user/bin/env node

@POST
const {id} = {AUTODESK_URL}oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objeckey/signed

@GET
{AUTODESK_URL}/oss/v2/signedresources/{id}?region=US //Stream Download
```

[image]

[image]

---

**TERMINAL** console things of axios and signedUrl
[image]

Comment: Your post does not cover the part of the report log that shows which argument failed to download. Can you check that and include it in the snapshot?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gkffYiGN

Comment: I get a 404 (not found) error on your pastebin.

Comment: check this
https://pastebin.com/sQvfxxDT

Comment: Add Image updated on Question also

Comment: Why do you have `pathInZip` for `InventorDoc` argument? Is the input file a zip file?

Comment: That Just name
'''pathInZip = MasterAssembly.iam''

i am sending InventoryParams (data:application/json,{height,width})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242124/discussion-between-rahul-bhobe-and-imbharat420).

Comment: `status : failedDownload` on **reportUrl**  
....This happened Just because of config callbackUrl 
Now reportUrl downloading Fine... 
or now ZIP file also downloading
**STILL other things like PDF,SVF,DWG downloading are blank**